# Android - Nested DragListView won't autoscroll when reached the edge

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, autoscroll

I use [this DragListView](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView) for my project. For the one with just one `DragListView` it works fine, it scrolled automatically when dragged item reached the top or bottom. But the problem occurs when I have a nested `DragListView`.

I have the outer `RecyclerView` inside the activity. This `RecyclerView` is populated by a custom adapter. And the custom item of that `RecyclerView` contains a `DragListView`. So the layout is like this:

```
<recyclerview>
   <item>
       <something like textview>
       <DragListView>
            <subitem/>
            <subitem/>
            <...../>
       </DragListView>
   </item>

   <item repeated...>...</item>
</recyclerview>
```

For the layout above, I can drag the subitem but it wont autoscroll when it reached both ends. After looking for the problem, I found that the criteria for scrolling is like "*You must not see the last or first item, because if you do, you're already at the top/bottom of the list*". The method they use to check if user've reached the top or bottom is:

```
    ViewHolder lastChild = findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    ViewHolder firstChild = findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(0);
```

If it's null, you haven't reached the top/bottom of the `DragListView`. If it's not null, you've reached the top/bottom of the `DragListView`.

However, Even though the last and first item are not currently on the screen (not laid out yet), the codes above always return a non-null `ViewHolder` the the system understands that it has reached the top/bottom so it won't scroll (while I'm still in the middle of the list, the first and last item is off the screen).

I guess the problem is because the `DragListView` has rendered all items so that user will have to scroll only the outer `RecyclerView`. (Scrolling both `RecyclerView` and `DragListView` may cause bad UX for users).

I tried to change the `setLayoutManager` `context` of the `DragListView` to `getApplicationContext()` which was passed from the Acitivity via the Adapter but no luck.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this problem? Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

After many days, I found a workaround for the problem. Instead of nesting the `DragListView`, now I make just one `DragListView` with many ViewHolder based on the `viewType` and then decided which item can be dragged my `setDragListCallback` for the `DragListView`. So now it won't render every items at once because every view is an item. Hope this helps someone.